# Optimize my sql Code using single sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables

---

```
-- Table  `user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `uid` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
------------------------------------------
Table `post`
------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `post` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
`pid` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` TEXT NULL,
  `by_uid` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `like_post`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `like_post` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `like_post` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_pid` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `liked_by` BIGINT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `favourite_post`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `favourite_post` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `favourite_post` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_pid` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `favourite_by` BIGINT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Data on Tables
User:

```
uid username    password    name
1   user1       pass1       User1 Name
2   user2       pass2       user2 name
```

Post:

```
Pid body            by_uid
1   This my body text   1
2   This is my body text2   2
3   This is my body text 3  1
```

Data on like_post:

```
Id  post_id         liked_by
1   1       2   //post id=1 liked by user=2
2   1       1   //post id=1 like by user=1
```

Data on Favourite_post

```
Id  post_id     favourite_by
1   1       1   //post id=1 favourited by user=1
2   2       1   //post id=2 favourited by user=1
```

I was trying to query using single string of sql, where as it was doing good with multiple sql queries.
I have a post area where I can be able to show it by using PDO execute
PHP Code to show post and like favourite etc

```
<?php
DBCon Class has the PDO Connection parameters
function selectQuery($str){
    $c=new DBCon();
    $con=$c->conN();
    $stmt=$con->prepare($str);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row=$stmt->fetch();
    return $row;
}
function selectQueries($str){
    $c=new DBCon();
    $con=$c->conN();
    $stmt=$con->prepare($str);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows=$stmt->fetchAll();
    return $rows;
}

$strPosts=”SELECT * FROM post”;
$rows=selectQueries($strPosts);
foreach($rows as $row){
    $pid=$row[‘pid’];
    echo $row[‘body’];
    $strLike=”SELECT * FROM like where post_pid=”.$pid.” LIMIT 1”;
    $rowLike=selectQuery($strLike);
    echo $rowLike[‘liked_by’];
    $strFav=”SELECT * FROM favourite WHERE post_pid=”.$pid.” LIMIT 1”;
    $rowFav=selectQuery($strFav);
    echo $rowFav[‘favourite_by’];
}
?>
```

This code was working fine while I have very less number of posts but if the post is large numbers this will make my page very slow. So how do I optimize it by using single code in SQL Query so that I can get all of the posts values, like values and favourite values.

Comment: You are using smart/curly quotes; replace them with normal quotes. Those alone will kill your code.

Comment: i have prepared this question  in office word 2013 so i am ok with that while in actual php code

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using `SQL JOINS`?

Comment: Run it the way you want it to run, but I suggest you don't use Word to "code" and paste your code from it. It makes many raise a brow, including myself whether it's part of actual code or part of any errors that could occur.

Comment: i have no idea how do i use sql join to return all the columns of every tables

Comment: Can you create a SQL fiddle for this?

Comment: hope this could help you to understand joins: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @user1054582 You may be OK with curly quotes, but I'm not. :-(

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com so that we can play around with your query and data to help optimize it.

Comment: Why do you use `LIMIT 1` in these queries ? Does it mean that you want to retrieve only one random "like" and one random "favorite" records for each post ?

Comment: Also, if you could show a result set which you expect, that will also help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not necessarily to use a single query (although that may make your life as a developer easier). The way to make it run quickly is indexing: the columns that you're joining on should have indexes.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT *
FROM User u
    JOIN Post p ON p.by_uid=u.uid
```

This simple example will get all users and their associated posts.

To make sure this runs efficiently, you need to add an index on `Post.by_uid` - this will allow the server to quickly find the appropriate posts for each user. Without an index, the server will have to scan every row in the `Post` table for each row in the `User` table, just to check & see if the `by_uid` value in that `Post` row matches the current `User.uid` value.

Comment: Ok but how do i get the like id and favourite id etc with this code